# Find a plane position in ARKit

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, arkit

I was trying to find the position of the closest Plane in my ARKit app. I wrote some code to help find it, but for some reason, when I run my app, it keeps crashing when I try to add an AR object to the plane. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
struct myPlaneCoords {

    var x = Float()
    var y = Float()
    var z = Float()
}

func getPlaneCoordinates(sceneView: ARSCNView) -> myPlaneCoords{//coordinates where an AR node will be added

    let cameraTransform = sceneView.session.currentFrame?.camera.transform
    let cameraCoordinates = MDLTransform(matrix: cameraTransform!)

    let camX = CGFloat(cameraCoordinates.translation.x)
    let camY = CGFloat(cameraCoordinates.translation.y)
    let cameraPosition = CGPoint(x: camX, y: camY)
    let anchors = sceneView.hitTest(cameraPosition, types: ARHitTestResult.ResultType.existingPlane)
    let spefAnchor = MDLTransform(matrix: anchors[0].localTransform)//finds closest plane

    var cc = myPlaneCoords()
    cc.x = spefAnchor.translation.x
    cc.y = spefAnchor.translation.y
    cc.z = spefAnchor.translation.z

    return cc  
}
```

Comment: Where's the crash? What's the precise error message?

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to judge w/o exception description.

I can assume that hitTest doesn't detect any anchor. 
In such case your `anchors` is empty.

```
let spefAnchor = MDLTransform(matrix: anchors[0].localTransform)//finds closest plane
```

And here you should get a crash.